# eclipse project - catkin run tests?

Tags: ros, catkin, gtest, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I built eclipse projects for my modules using catkin_make -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" but it did not create test targets.  It seems that eclipse is set up to just run make this way, and trying to run target test, run_tests, etc. does not work.

Alternatively, is there a way to make catkin_make (and make without arguments in the build directory) build and run the tests by default?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195893/eclipse-project---catkin-run-tests?/) by [EEngineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/14886/eengineer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not specific to Eclipse. You have to run CMake with the flag `-DCATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING=1` in order to configure the packages with their tests.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1